# How do I use today's date in a folder path

Tags: c#

So I am creating lots of folders  as part o fum jobs say and part of the naming strategy is to use today's date as part of the Path
When I use DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() I keep getting a forward slash
Is there anyway to stop that or any other strategy to use the date in a temporary folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

This will replace the default separator from `/` to `-`. Where `-` is a valid character in folder name.

You can also use DateTime.Today for current date.

```
string temp = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Comment: Or even "yyyyMMdd" without any delimiters if readability is not critical.

Comment: @Artemix, sure that could be one way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

As an aside...

You may also like to reverse the order or the parts of the date if you want to make the file names sortable.

For example,

```
var filename = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "-Photo-Capture.png";
```

would allow you to sort the files on the date they were created.  Using a standard format date would still allow you to sort, but you'll see all file created on the first day of any month, any year, then all files created on the 2nd, etc.